# How to reset AWS CloudWatch alarm after the wanted change that triggered it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I am adding CloudWatch alarm for IAM policy changes but I am wondering what do I do when I want to add an IAM policy? The alarm will be activated but the change is wanted. How do I set alarm to be deactivated again? Is that the process in this situation (reseting alarm somehow when the change is made) or I am missing the process completely?

Comment: You do not reset alarms, they reset themselves when the underlying metric changes again causing them to transition into OK.

Comment: @luk2302 And how do you reset underlying metric? The alarm was triggered by the change I made and I want that change to be a part of desired state. The alarm will be in Alarm state if I don't do something, right? And I want it to be in OK state including the change I made. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to be way more specific in what alert and metric you have and use. You can also change the alert to no longer alert on e.g. threshold 17 but on 18 from now on. Really depends on what your setup is. The metrics and alerts I use automatically recover normally, e.g. alerting on message age in a Queue fixes itself as soon as I consume and delete the messages. Metrics on logged lambda ERRORs automatically recover after a couple of minutes because there simply were no more errors in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: @luk2302 I am not sure how to do it so I will provide an example.

This is part of the filter I use for the metric:

FilterPattern: "{...($.eventName=PutUserPolicy)||($.eventName=CreatePolicy)||($.eventName=DeletePolicy)||($.eventName=CreatePolicyVersion)||($.eventName=AttachUserPolicy)...}"

So, it triggers an alarm when, for example, I create a policy. That is the point this alarm goes into Alarm state.
The thing is I want to have that policy I have just created, and I would like the alarm to go to OK state with new policy in place.
How do I do that?